# What is the min_density parameter in scikit-learn Random Forest/ExtraTrees for?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn

The [ExtraTreesClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier) and [Random Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier) in Scikit learn library has a parameter "min_density". Its default value is set to 0.1.

I cannot figure out what this min_density parameter means and how it affects the training (It is not in the docs and I cannot find its equivalent in the paper.) Can someone kindly explain the effect of this parameter on training and how to properly set it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The min_density parameter has been deprecated in the latest 0.14 version of scikit-learn. It was an implementation-specific parameter controlling a trade-off between speed and memory space. It does not affect the accuracy of your model.

With the latest version of scikit-learn, the implementation of decision trees has been rewritten and this parameter has been removed. I recommend you to update your version of scikit-learn. Trees are now much faster than before (from 1x to 20x depending on your dataset and settings).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read that the latest version 0.14 of scikit-learn has improved the speed of the Tree-based classifier but I haven't had the time to upgrade yet. I'll definitely take a look at it in due time. Thanks.